# The probability of the union of an increasing sequence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am self-studying "Probability Theory: A Concise Course" by Rozanov and do not fully understand Theorem 2.3:

If $A_1,A_2,...$ is an "increasing sequence" of events, i.e., a sequence such that $A_1\subset A_2\subset...$, then $$P(\cup_k A_k)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(A_n).$$

**Why is the limit on the right hand side?** It seems true that if there are a finite number of events $A_1\subset A_2\subset...\subset A_n$ then $$P(\cup_k A_k)=P(A_n).$$ If this is the case for any $n$ then why does the author put emphasis on the $n\rightarrow\infty$ case? It's not that I am unconvinced that the result is true, rather that I think there must be extra information encoded in that result which I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

For an (infinite) increasing sequence $A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots$ with union $A:=\cup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$, what is being asserted is that
$$
P(A) =\lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n).
$$
Notice that for each $n$, $A\supset \cup_{k=1}^n A_k=A_n$.